# How to render Google map into Grails view

Tags: javascript, google-maps, grails, gsp

I'm developing a web app that has a embedded map, seted with LatLong, but I just can't get it rendered into my GSP view. This is my GSP code:

```
<%@ page import="cr.consultingservices.DA.Avaluo" %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta name="layout" content="main">
        <g:set var="entityName" value="${message(code: 'avaluo.label', default: 'Avaluo')}" />
        <title><g:message code="default.show.label" args="[entityName]" /></title>

        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <style>
            #map {
                height: 100%;
                overflow:visible;
                background-color:black;
            }
    </style>

    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="#show-avaluo" class="skip" tabindex="-1"><g:message code="default.link.skip.label" default="Skip to content&hellip;"/></a>
        <div class="nav" role="navigation">
            <ul>
                <li><a class="home" href="${createLink(uri: '/')}"><g:message code="Home"/></a></li>
                <li><g:link class="list" action="index"><g:message code="Mis avaluos" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
                <li><g:link class="create" action="create"><g:message code="Crear avaluo" args="[entityName]" /></g:link></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="show-avaluo" class="content scaffold-show" role="main">
            <h1 style="color:#0B77B8"><g:message code="Mi avaluo" args="[entityName]" /></h1>
            <g:if test="${flash.message}">
            <div class="message" role="status">${flash.message}</div>
            </g:if>
            <ol class="property-list avaluo">

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.descripcion}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="descripcion-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="avaluo.descripcion.label" default="Descripcion" /></span>

                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="descripcion-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${avaluoInstance}" field="descripcion"/></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.latitud}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="latitud-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="avaluo.latitud.label" default="Latitud" /></span>

                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="latitud-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${avaluoInstance}" field="latitud"/></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.longitud}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span  style="color:#939598" id="longitud-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="avaluo.longitud.label" default="Longitud" /></span>

                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="longitud-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${avaluoInstance}" field="longitud"/></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.provincia}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="provincia-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="avaluo.provincia.label" default="Provincia" /></span>

                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="provincia-label">${avaluoInstance?.provincia?.encodeAsHTML()}</span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.canton}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="canton-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="avaluo.canton.label" default="Canton" /></span>

                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="canton-label">${avaluoInstance?.canton?.encodeAsHTML()}</span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.otrasSenas}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="otrasSenas-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="avaluo.otrasSenas.label" default="Otras Senas" /></span>

                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="otrasSenas-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${avaluoInstance}" field="otrasSenas"/></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <script>
                var map;
                function initMap() {
                  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
                    center: {lat: -34.397, lng: 150.644},
                    zoom: 8
                  });
                }
                </script>
                <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyATyoneVleIc_TNlkML6km1YfLw_LxO99Q&callback=initMap"
                async defer></script>



                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="map-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="mapa" default="Mapa" /></span>
                    <div id="map">
                    </div>
                </li>


                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.creador}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="creador-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="avaluo.creador.label" default="Creador" /></span>

                    <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="creador-label"><g:link controller="usuario" style="color:black;" action="show" id="${avaluoInstance?.creador?.id}">${avaluoInstance?.creador?.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.comentarios}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="comentarios-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="avaluo.comentarios.label" default="Comentarios" /></span>

                        <g:each in="${avaluoInstance.comentarios}" var="c">
                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="comentarios-label"><g:link controller="comentario" action="show" id="${c.id}">${c?.encodeAsHTML()}</g:link></span>
                        </g:each>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen1}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen1-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 1" default="Imagen 1" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen2}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen2-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 2" default="Imagen 2" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen3}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen3-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 3" default="Imagen 3" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen4}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen4-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 4" default="Imagen 4" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen5}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen5-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 5" default="Imagen 5" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen6}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen6-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 6" default="Imagen 6" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen7}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen7-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 7" default="Imagen 7" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen8}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen8-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 8" default="Imagen 8" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen9}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen9-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 9" default="Imagen 9" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.imagen10}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="imagen10-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="Imagen 10" default="Imagen 10" /></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

                <g:if test="${avaluoInstance?.valorEstimado}">
                <li class="fieldcontain">
                    <span style="color:#939598" id="valorEstimado-label" class="property-label"><g:message code="avaluo.valorEstimado.label" default="Valor Estimado" /></span>

                        <span class="property-value" aria-labelledby="valorEstimado-label"><g:fieldValue bean="${avaluoInstance}" field="valorEstimado"/></span>

                </li>
                </g:if>

            </ol>
            <g:form url="[resource:avaluoInstance, action:'delete']" method="DELETE">
                <fieldset class="buttons">
                    <g:link class="edit" action="edit" resource="${avaluoInstance}"><g:message code="Editar" default="Edit" /></g:link>
                    <g:actionSubmit class="delete" action="delete" value="Borrar avaluo" onclick="return confirm('${message(code: 'Esta seguro?', default: 'Esta seguro?')}');" />
                </fieldset>
            </g:form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see, I didn't even removed the `Google` example latitude and longitude, to check if it was an error with my coordinates.
I know that the script is not placed in the best place of the view, but I just left it there to have better comprehension. What is happening is that it just goes blank, doesn't show an error or nothing.
I'm kind of new to `Grails` and `Javascript`, so any help will be deeply appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: if the answer works, accept it. If not, please explain what's not working.

Comment: To be honest with you, I haven't try it out yet, so once I do, I will response this. I promise, I won't forget

Comment: I think you forgot.

Comment: @CharlesMcKelvey thanks for reminding me. I did forgot, but the answer did work. Accepting now. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to call the `initMap()` function after page is loaded. Now it's just initialized, but never executed. 
Add this after your initMap initialization (before the end of your script tag).
`window.addEventListener('load', initMap, false )`

Comment: And what about if I want to load the map after the text of 2 fields are changed?

Comment: then you should check with javascript - on textfield changes. See with IF what you want the user to write there and then initialize. [See fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/70861x1q/4/)

Comment: And if my post has answered your initial question, it'd be nice if you accepted the answer.

Comment: If it does, I certainly will :)

Comment: Well.. It does! :D